# Why "query" does not return any value

Tags: node.js, next.js, mysql2

I've been stuck on this part of my code since yesterday. I would like to be able to return a result so I can parse it and do something on the front-end. I created an endpoint where I will check if the user is registered on my site. The problem is that I don't know why my code does not return anything. A little help?

```
// api/login/index.js

import { db } from '../server/db.js';

export default async function(req, res){
    const [email, password] = [req.body[0], req.body[1]];
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if(err) throw err;

        db.query('SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [email, password], function(error, result, fields) {
            console.log(error, result, fields); // returns nothing
            db.release();

            if(error) throw error;

        });
    })
};
```

```
// db.js

require('dotenv').config({path: '/.env'});
const sql = require('mysql2/promise');

export const db = sql.createPool({
    host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_USERNAME,
    database: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_NAME,
    password: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_PASSWORD,
    waitForConnections: true,
    queueLimit: 0
});
```

Comment: log the sql statement generated please?

Comment: What happens if you remove `AND password = ?` from your SQL? Usually passwords are stored in a hashed format, not verbatim.

Comment: nothing happens, I can't even access the query made by "db.query()"